# I have a Vuejs/nuxt app - I need to make same app for with another style and deploy on same server

Tags: apache, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an existing VueJs/nuxt app. The same app but with different CSS/ Images need to be deployed on same server (different URL) - its the same app but for another client.
Currently what we do is pull the branch on the Linux server and execute npm run generate for the current app.
I presume we need to generate the other app into another folder.
Is this the best solution? Then how do we configure for the new URL to point to this new folder.
example : current URL is [www.potato.com](http://www.potato.com) and new url for will be [www.potato.com/newclient](http://www.potato.com/newclient)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Reverse Proxy with Nginx and launch both apps in different ports.
Let's say that potato.com will be in port 4000 and potato.com/newclient will be in port 5000.

You basically state that in your Nginx

```
server {
  servername www.potato.com
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
  }
  location /newclient {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
  }
}
```

Now your apps can live anywhere in your file system. Just deploy them with different ports.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. This is what I have done up to now - I deployed the two apps on different folders and used apache virtual host to serve it on two different ports - 82 and 84 - both run well. Now I want to set up the reverse proxy as pointed in your answer. I want to keep using apache to server the apps but use nginx only as reverse proxy  - is that ok? pls advise

Comment: Yeah, definitely! I have that same setup you’re talking about on a server. Change Apache’s listening port to 8080, this will make ngoni the main entry point for http connections since it’ll be listening on ports 80 and 443, and then using reverse proxy you can redirect to whatever virtual host you have on Apache, simply by redirecting to the virtual host on port 8080 (where Apache will be listening). Hope it works!